# Android Jetpack Compose: Unresolved reference: Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I've been building an app entirely with Jetpack Compose and I have noticed that in the last 3 o 4 canary versions of the Android Studio, the tools are getting worse and worse (at least for me) because I can see now CPU at 200% and especially, missing references.

So I have a `Toolbar` component and I have an action to share a certain screen with other uses by using `Intent.createChooser`. This is already working, because I created it with previous
versions of the AS Canary but now, always get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: Intent
Unresolved reference: action
Unresolved reference: putExtra
Unresolved reference: type
```

This is the code I'm using inside my `TopAppBar`:

```
actions = {
            if (addShareButton) {
                val context = AmbientContext.current
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        viewState.job?.let {
                            val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
                                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I have found a remote job! ${it.url}")
                                type = "text/plain"
                            }
                            val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
                            context.startActivity(shareIntent)
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Share)
                }
            }
```

Also, AS gives a warning saying that the the variable `context` defined in the line `val context = AmbientContext.current` is never used, but it is in the line `context.startActivity(shareIntent)`.

Am I doing something wrong? It is now impossible to code anything because of this and other errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still have an `import` statement for `Intent` in this file? FWIW, I have been sticking with 4.2 Canary 16 for Compose experiments -- I have not yet bothered with a 4.3 canary release.

Comment: even using the explicit definition such as `val shareIntent = android.content.Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)`, this still happens. It looks like the problem might be the AS version itself